# Fake a landscape view in portrait only mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, orientation

I have seen a similar question on Android but my question targets iOS. My app is **portrait only** and I have set up a landscape view which I would like to add to my current view, but there is no autorotation, the user manually rotates the device.

I have tried doing this but when I add it as a subview the view it comes out like this:

[image]

So as you can see it adds it as if the view is in landscape mode, how can I modify this? Thanks!

Comment: present it modally with nav controller

Comment: @NeverBe How can I present a view modally? I am not presenting a view controller, I am just adding a subview. And also I do not have a navigation controller in my app

Comment: is it problem place view in controller, and present modally nav controller with this view controller?

Comment: @NeverBe Im sorry? I don't quite understand what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the view 480 wide and 320 tall in Interface Builder. Then use:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  myLandscapeView.transform =CGAffineTransformMake(0,1,-1,0,-80,80);
  [self.view addSubview:myLandscapeView];
}
```